# How to wire new outlet? (US)4 sets of wires

Tags: electrical

Last night I had an outlet short out. From opening it and seeing the type, I can see why. I've installed and changed outlets, motors, etc before, but this one has me a bit stumped. There are two sets of wires to the top, and two to the bottom of the outlet, not just your typical line and load which you would pigtail. How would I go about wiring this to your typical household outlet? There's no gcfi.

[image]

Comment: Is this a pre-fab home or mobile home? I'd be just cutting it all off and starting fresh.

Comment: Mobile home. I intend on cutting out the burnt part and installing a normal outlet with the screws holding the wires on, not that no strip push in crap. Just has me stumped that there's 4 sets of wire, not 2

Comment: Label hot and neutral carefully. Typically, if you keep each set connected you're fine. This assumes a single circuit (all on the same breaker).

Comment: Judging from the push in type outlet, I'm assuming all of the blacks are connected to each other, same with all the whites, etc. Would i wire nut each bunch of 4 of the same color together and pigtail to the new outlet? So in total 5 wires on each wire nut? I've just never seen this before

Comment: I'll leave it to a sparky to provide a good answer, but probably. Sometimes I've relied on the two sets of screws a standard outlet provides (and the jumper between them) to ease nut loading. You can create two bundles for each color and jumper each to a screw. Opinions vary on that approach.

Comment: Well, I got lucky and our electrician showed up at work today, he suggested that I wire nut each group of 4 like wires together along with a pigtail, run that to the outlet. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please provide an answer below and accept it or delete your question.

Answer (score 2):

Group all like wires together, so the 4 white, the 4 black, the 4 ground, each color separate from the others. Add a pigtail (short length of wire) of the same color to each group of wires, and wire nut them together. Connect the pigtail to the appropriate spot on the outlet